# Determine if two objects have an identical structure with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, javascript-objects

I'm working on a React application which has multiple themes. Each theme should have the same structure, which can feature deeply-nested properties, but will have different values. It's the structure I'm wanting to add a test case for.

I'm wanting to use Jest to determine if the structure of each of my themes are identical to ensure that no properties have been missed.

All of my theme objects have an identical structure but with different properties. They're set up similar to this:

```js
{
  brand: '...',
  navigation: {
    background: '...',
    link: {
      background: '...',
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm aware of properties like `toEqual` and `toMatchObject`, but both of these fail if I directly try to compare two themes with one another:

```js
expect(themeA).toMatchObject(themeB);
```

This fails because the *values* of each property are different. For example, `themeA` has a `brand` property set to `'#ABC'` whereas `themeB` has the same property set to  `'#DEF'`.

I'm also aware that a structure can be defined using Jest like this:

```js
expect(themeA).toEqual({
  brand: expect.any(String),
  navigation: {
    background: expect.any(String),
    ...
  },
  ...
})
```

...but this would require updating the test case every time a new property is added or removed, which I feel complicates the purpose of the test.

Is there a simple way to test if two objects have the same structure but different values?

Comment: have you considered using snapshot testing instead?

Comment: @Peter I don't think that would work as I'm using JSS which only outputs class names and not the raw style values. I'm not really wanting a thorough test of my application, just a quick failsafe on the build step to point out that a theme has a missing property.

Comment: "Is there a simple way to test if two objects have the same structure but different values?"  this is usually accomplished with using `expect.any(String)` etc like you show at the bottom of your question or you ignore running unit tests and use a static types such as TS or Flow.

Comment: @Peter to achieve that I believe I'd have to define each property first? The theme files I'm working with each have several hundred properties and I don't have a need to perform type matching as the compiler would fail to apply the properties if they weren't strings (or objects containing child properties with strings) anyway.

Comment: Note that the objects in your question end with a semicolon and not with a comma (`background: '...';`). Is that a typo?

Comment: @mgarcia well spotted, yes that's just a typo. The theme files I'm dealing with are hundreds of lines long, so this post just contains an example of the sort of structure they contain, not the exact structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by implementing a custom matcher. The matchers jest has can be extended by using the [`extend`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) method.

As a **proof of concept**, you can define a `toMatchStructure` matcher like this:

```
function hasEqualStructure(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.keys(obj1).every(key => {
        const v = obj1[key];

        if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) {
            return hasEqualStructure(v, obj2[key]);
        }

        return obj2.hasOwnProperty(key);
    });
}

export default function toMatchStructure(actual, expected) {
    const pass = hasEqualStructure(actual, expected);

    return {
        message: () => `expected ${expected} to match structure ${actual}`,
        pass
    };
}
```

Note that this matcher does not take into account edge cases (does not check if the objects are null). Also, the matcher will pass if `obj2` is a superset of `obj1` (i.e. has the same properties plus some extra properties that are not present in `obj1`). Furthermore, it is only checking that the keys are present, but it could be extended to check that the type of the values in those properties are the same. You can also edit the returned `message` so that is more user friendly for the tests that fail.

Having that in mind, you can now extend jest matchers by calling:

```
expect.extend({
   toMatchStructure,
});
```

Ideally, you would do this in a file that would be executed through the [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) jest config option.

Once you have the setup done, you can call your matcher in the test:

```
expect(themeA).toMatchStructure(themeB);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all different values from your object and leave just a structure - then you could simply compare two structures using basic jest `toEqual`:

```js
const obj1 = {
    brand: 'brand 1',
    navigation: { opacity: 0.2 },
};
const obj2 = {
    brand: 'brand 2',
    navigation: { opacity: 0.5 },
};

function normalizeObject(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (_key, value) => (
        typeof value !== 'object' ? '-' : value
    ));
}

// then you could compare structures of 2 objects:
// expect(normalizeObject(obj1)).toEqual(normalizeObject(obj2));

// or verify if every element from some array have the same structure:
const themeArray = [obj1, obj2, obj1];
themeArray.forEach((theme) => {
    // expect(normalizeObject(theme)).toEqual(normalizeObject(themeArray[0]));
});

// according to number of different types in your comparable objects you may want to modify normalizeObject function a little
function normalizeObject(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (_key, value) => {
        switch (typeof value) {
            case 'number': return 0;
            case 'string': return '-';
            case 'boolean': return true;
            // case ...: return ...;
            default: return value;
        }
    });
}

console.log({
    original: obj1,
    normalized: normalizeObject(obj1),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what Typescript will catch everywhere, automatically.  You won't really need to write tests for this type of thing.

```
type ThemeA = {
  brand: string,
  navigation: {
    background: string,
    link?: {
      background: string,
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}

myStyle = { ... }

myStyle: ThemeA   // this will be highlighted by your IDE 
                  // if it's not a match, even in tests.
```

Comment: In a typed environment, I don't see why you would need to write unit tests confirming the type.